webview_flutter not Working on Android with some URLs
I'm using webview_flutter to open a webveiw in my app, but it's not working when I'm trying to open this URL:
https://gwapi.naps.ma:8085/napspayment/authorization/
note:
- it works perfectly on IOS devices.
- it works when I open the same URL in Android browsers.
- other URLs works on the app like: https://pub.dev/
here is the complete code of my webview widget:
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:wmr/src/core/constants/styles.dart';
import 'package:wmr/src/features/payment/presentation/bloc/payement_bloc.dart';

class BuyCoinsView extends StatefulWidget {
  final int amount;
  const BuyCoinsView({super.key, required this.amount});

  @override
  BuyCoinsViewState createState() => BuyCoinsViewState();
}

class BuyCoinsViewState extends State<BuyCoinsView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<PayementBloc>().add(PayementRequested(widget.amount));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "buy_coins".tr(),
          style: TextStyles.poppinsMedium.copyWith(
            fontSize: 24,
            color: AppColors.white,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<PayementBloc, PayementState>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is PayementUrlGenerated) {
            log("the recived url is : ${state.url}");
            return WebViewWidget(
              controller: WebViewController()
                ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
                ..setOnConsoleMessage((JavaScriptConsoleMessage message) {
                  log(">>>>>>>>>>>> JavaScriptConsoleMessage: ${message.message}");
                })
                ..setNavigationDelegate(
                  NavigationDelegate(
                    onProgress: (int progress) {
                      log(">>>>>>>>>>>> progress: $progress");
                    },
                    onPageStarted: (String url) {
                      log(">>>>>>>>>>> page started: $url");
                    },
                    onPageFinished: (String url) {},
                    onHttpError: (HttpResponseError error) {
                      log(">>>>>>>>>>> onHttpError: $error");
                    },
                    onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
                      log(">>>>>>>>>>> onWebResourceError: $error");
                    },
                    onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
                      log(">>>>>>>>>>> onNavigationRequest: ${request.url}");
                      return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                    },
                  ),
                )
                ..loadRequest(
                  Uri.parse(state.url),
                ),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: AppColors.primary,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

the recived url is : https://gwapi.naps.ma:8085/napspayment/authorization/token/.....
I/PlatformViewsController(10855): Hosting view in view hierarchy for platform view: 0
I/PlatformViewsController(10855): PlatformView is using SurfaceProducer backend
[log] >>>>>>>>>>>> progress: 10
E/FrameEvents(10855): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D/EGL_emulation(10855): app_time_stats: avg=114061.26ms min=114061.26ms max=114061.26ms count=1
E/FrameEvents(10855): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D/EGL_emulation(10855): app_time_stats: avg=602.22ms min=26.81ms max=1177.63ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation(10855): app_time_stats: avg=593.65ms min=20.12ms max=1167.18ms count=2
E/FrameEvents(10855): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D/EGL_emulation(10855): app_time_stats: avg=54.96ms min=6.11ms max=1189.22ms count=27
E/FrameEvents(10855): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/chromium(10855): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
[log] >>>>>>>>>>>> progress: 100


Hey @Abdeljalil Bouchfar, I'd recommend debugging this further by going to chrome://inspect/#devices on your computer that your device is connected too, and you should be able to see your webview show up there, then look for JavaScript errors in the console because that's probably what's causing it to fail :)
